# Remove trailing whitespace in languages where whitespace does not matter

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, whitespace

Sometimes I have seen questions with a ridiculous amount of trailing whitespace. This wouldn't bother me so much if the scrollbar wouldn't appear:

```c
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
```

It might also be that the code is indented a lot and the trailing whitespace tips the scale:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++)
          for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                  thisVariableIWillIncrementAlsoILoveCamelcase += whyNotMultiply;
```

It would be nice if when a language where whitespace doesn't matter is specified,
trailing whitespace would be ignored.

Comment: If a mechanism can detect that, then I'd rather see an automatic downvote instead! ;-) (Seriously: we need to teach folks to put some effort in their questions.)

Comment: What languages require egregious amounts of whitespace tacked on at the end of a line???  I mean, other than the Whitespace language.

Comment: @Won't: Well, none that I know of, but it would be kind of wrong to mess with the whitespace if whitespace is meaningfull in the language.  For instance if I posted some code, didn't mark it as any particular language and the question is something like "Why does my machine make a weird grinding noise when I try to parse this with obseleteParser™?" It just might be the case that the whitespace is significant, but when the prettifier thinks it is C++, it should be safe. In the rare (I haven't seen a single case of this yet) case where it is significant one can always add "language: lang-none".

Comment: In addition of the automatic removal of trailing whitespace, I would also like to see the automatic removal of empty lines (when there is a block larger than one present)

Comment: <irony>I have an almost overwhelming urge to remove the unnecessary whitespace in this question</irony>

Comment: If you wanted any proof that this happens, here is a recent one: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17427649/revisions